# How can I quickly test firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working with Typescript on firebase functions. As I have been developing I have found it very difficult to test (or experiment) with the code. I am using the Lint plugin so at leased I see the errors withought having to run the code.

But I am not able to run the code and see what is outputed:

I have the following code which I would like to fix-up and test:

```
    export const onPostUpdate = functions.database
.ref('/Posts/{uid}/{postID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const uid = context.params.uid
  const postID = context.params.postID
  console.log('New postID:', postID)
  console.log('New uid:', uid)

  // const postData = snapshot.val()
  // console.log('New postData: ${postData["Media"]}')

  export const getUsersToBeUpdated = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin.database().doc('PeopleWhoFollowMe/\(uid)').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.data()
      response.send(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //handle error
      console.log(error)
      response.status(500).send(error)
    })
  })
  return console.log('New postID:', postID)
})
```

In this case I do not know what this would output: `response.send(data)`.

**So What are my options for quicker testing?**

### Update:

Based on my [question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266654/i-functions-your-functions-could-not-be-parsed-due-to-an-issue-with-your-node-m?noredirect=1#comment99150715_56266654) It seems that I cannot emulate Realtime Database triggers as its not supported yet. Given this, what are my options for quick testing?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: for: firebase emulators:start, should I be cd ing into the project directory? @DougStevenson

Comment: I don't think it will work any other way.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did so and now I am getting: the feedback seen above. I tried doing what the response requests but it seems to not be responding. do I have to exit or is something else wrong?

Comment: If you have a new question about how the emulator works, please post it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a project which has background functions (onUpdate, OnCreate) and HTTP functions. **The easiest way I found to test them, was using simple unit tests.**

Testing should be part of your programming life. It can feel cumbersome at first but it will save you a lot of time, especially with cloud functions

In your code, it seems you wrote two functions. One is a database trigger and the other is an HTTP function.

I'll try to write tests for each to show you how I would do it. I use [jest](https://jestjs.io/)

```
/functions
|--index.js
|--onCreate.js
|--getUsersToBeUpdated.js
|--/test
   |--onCreate.spec.js
   |--getUsersToBeUpdated.spec.js
```

### index.js

```
const functions   = require('firebase-functions');

const onCreate    = require('./onCreate');
const getUsersToBeUpdated  = require('./getUsersToBeUpdated');

module.exports.onCreate = functions.database.ref('/Posts/{uid}/{postID}').onCreate(onCreate);
module.exports.getUsersToBeUpdated = functions.https.onRequest(getUsersToBeUpdated);
```

### onCreate.spec.js

```
const onCreate = require('../onCreate');

let snapshot; 
let context;

beforeEach(() => {
    snapshot = {
        val: jest.fn()
    };

    context = {
        params: {id: 'ID_SOME_POST_ID'}
    };

});

test('that it should do something onCreate POST', () => {
    onCreate(snapshot, context);

    expect(snapshot.val).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

### getUsersToBeUpdated.spec.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const getUsersToBeUpdated = require(../getUsersToBeUpdated);

// we need to mock the funcionality of firebase-admin 
jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => {
    const admin = {};
    const snapshot = {
        data: jest.fn(() => ({propA: 'a', propB: 'b'}))
    };

    const admin.database = jest.fn(() => admin);
    const admin.doc = jest.fn(() => admin);
    const admin.get = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(snapshot));

    return admin;
});

let response;
let request;

beforeEach(() => {
    response = {};
    response.status = jest.fn();
    response.send = jest.fn();
    request = jest.fn();
});

// this function makes asynchronous requests so for simplicity Ill use async/await
test('that should return a successful request', async () => {
    await getUsersToBeUpdated(request, response);

    expect(response.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({propA: 'a', propB: 'b'});
});

// this function makes asynchronous requests so for simplicity Ill use async/await
test('that should return a error request', async () => {
    const error = {code: 123, message: 'some error'};

    //force the get function to fail
    admin.get.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.reject(error));

    await getUsersToBeUpdated(request, response);

    expect(response.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);
    expect(response.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
});
```

Comment: SO I will need to make the folders you have shown, which only house that specific functionality? Also I am using typescript, does that make a diference here?

Comment: @NCT127 you can set your folder structure how ever you want. I just showed you how it worked for me. If you are using typescript you will need to some small changes but my real point is that you should use unit testing to make your life easier with cloud functions.