# i functions: Your functions could not be parsed due to an issue with your node_modules (see above)

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

In relation to this question I am trying to `firebase emulators:start` but I get the bellow output. Which when I type and press enter does nothing now.

```
i  Starting emulators: ["functions"]
⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "12"
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "/Users/username/Desktop/FinalAppPrjv2/firefunctions/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-functions-test" to be installed as a development dependency. To fix this, run "npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test" in your functions directory.
i  functions: Your functions could not be parsed due to an issue with your node_modules (see above)
cd functions
pwd
npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test
```

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: Did you run `npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test` in your `functions` directory, like the message says?

Comment: I opened a new tap (cant belive I didnt do that before!) and ran the comands, then I went back to the other tap I was originaly on and I now see the following (And the cursor is just at the bottom left not letting me execute anything):i  Your code has been provided a "firebase-admin" instance.
Ignoring trigger "onPostUpdate" because the service "firebaseio.com" is not yet supported.
 @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to emulate Realtime Database triggers, which (as the error message says) is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error shows emulation of Realtime Database triggers is not supported yet. There is no way around this, as of writing this.